# One Regex for word and non-wor character

Tags: regex

So I've a message payload like this,

```
**GS***RL*CITGO*JJ*20090518*1036*25110*X*00405\n
ST*423*2511*RT**GS***08247
```

I also another message payload like this,

```
**#**UPT     0000SWSAM001203081454NS      /\n
GS*QM*TRSC*UPDS  *20120309*0820*0309***#***004010
```

Now in both the above examples, I want a single regex which will just find 1 occurrence of `GS` or `#` (even though the search string is inside the payload as well)

I know I could use `^` to identify the start of string but it doesn't seem to work for both of my use cases

Comment: @snipes83 Isn't that the same as `/GS|#/` ?

Comment: @millimoose also isn't `/GS|#/` the same as `/G(S|#)/`?

Comment: @snipes83 Wrong. Your RE will match everything up to and including the **last** occurence of `GS` or `#`: http://ideone.com/rmQhcA (Then again, that means I'm wrong about them being the same.)

Comment: @snipes83 Wrong again: http://ideone.com/aOLXLZ - `/foo|bar` seems to be equivalent to `/(foo)|(bar)/`. (I'm not sure why exactly the `fooar` and `foobar` test cases aren't failing when it seems they should, but the RE certainly isn't interpreted the way you think it is.)

Comment: Which flavor of regex? What do you want to match and/or capture after "finding" this occurence? Can you please highlight which occurence of which you would like to match in your examples?

Comment: Anyway, my point remains. You do not want to use `.*` as "skip anything that doesn't match" because REs are greedy, and then backtrack when a match fails. (This also implies the performance of doing so is pretty terrible since it likely backs up character by character.) You want to either use `.*?` and a capture group, but your RE engine might not support nongreedy matching; or use an unanchored search and expression, like Python's `re.search()`, which should in any sane RE implementation find the **first** match in a string.

Comment: We'll need to know a little more to be able to tell if you'll need a multi-line declaration. So, if you're using PHP, C++, Javascript, or some random text editor.

Comment: which part of the text is your target in? before the \n or after?

Answer (score 0):

Use a look-ahead to assert that your search term lies *before* the `\n` character:

```
((GS)|#)(?=.*\n)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will match `GS` or `#`. I've escaped the `#`, as I'm not sure which language or app you're using for your request. Each program and programming language has a slightly different implementation of REGEX with different flags and matching across new lines.

PHP's (PCRE) Style:

```
/(GS|\#)/
```

Typical Regex `OR` statement

```
(GS|\#)
```

Comment: In standard regexps, `(` and `)` aren't "special", `\(` and `\)` are. Also it's not PCRE style to surround a RE in slashes - the slashes aren't *part of* the RE, they're delimiters *around* regexp literals in Perl and Ruby and Javascript. (In fact, Perl and Ruby probably allow several types of delimiters.) You put them into the pattern in PHP because PHP doesn't have first-class regexp literals but still kind of wants to have them.

Comment: @millimoose I frequently use `!` characters myself as delimiters and am well aware. Depending on the application they're using I was providing my answer with delimiters so if the OP threw the answer into something like `preg_replace()` they wouldn't get an error. `PCRE` is how `PHP` refers to their implementation. I've performed `REGEX` matches with about 30 different applications and 10 different languages and was referring to how some implementations match newlines and others do not; not referring to the implementation of the slashes. They may even be using `grep`.

Comment: PCRE is a specific library that's usable outside of PHP, and near as I can tell it doesn't inherently require the slashes. That's the only difference between your two examples, and it's (subtly) inaccurate to say it's a PCRE-ism.

Comment: @millimoose Take it up with PHP. I'm using their terminology. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Comment: What I'm trying to say is there's a distinction between "the style of the PCRE library" and "the style that PHP's PCRE extension uses" (which is rather idiosyncratic). Your phrasing is ambiguous an I just wanted to clear it up, I didn't mean it as a knock against your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your language supports an *unanchored search* through the string (it probably does - it's how e.g. `sed` and `grep` operate), just use whatever the equivalent of this Python code would be:

```
import re

payload = '''**GS***RL*CITGO*JJ*20090518*1036*25110*X*00405
ST*423*2511*RT**GS***08247'''

needle = r'GS|#'

match = re.search(needle, payload) # search() is unanchored

# index of the first matched character
print match.start() #> 2

# index of the first character after the match
print match.end() #> 4

# prints the substring the RE matched
print payload[match.start(), match.end()] #> GS
```

ideone example: http://ideone.com/USvlTk